# How do I clear Steam Cloud Sync files for a specific game?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, macos, steam-cloud

I have some bad config data stored in Steam Cloud Sync for TF2.  I've tried clearing all local files, passing in `-autoexec` as a launch option, and even doing a complete reinstall of the game and while I can disable Cloud Sync to reset all of my configs, as soon as I turn it back on it downloads my saved config data.  I want to be able to clear all of my cloud data and reset it back to the default config.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had success (different game) in the past with this guide (the Steam app ID for TF2 is `440`): http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2470784

The basic idea is to:

1. mess up (i.e. empty) the local backup data
2. start Steam and receive a *Sync conflict* dialog
3. delete the local backup data *without closing the dialog*
4. resolve the conflict in the dialog by uploading your local (erased) data

I have no Mac experience with it, buy the only Windows-specific details there are the use of PowerShell and the install paths.
For step **I.2**, you can use this (Linux tested) shell command to empty all files in the folder (the install folder is assumed to be correct, but I can't test on Mac to confirm), replacing **steam ID** with you own (there should be only one folder):

```
cd "~/Library/Application Support/Steam/userdata/<steam ID>/440/remote"
ls * | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c "echo '' > {}"
```

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @angussidney agreed, my concern is that there are too many steps to the process, and copypasting them would not be effective. I shall though expand on the Mac-compatible alternative to the Window shell steps.

Comment: @Viruzzo This advice is given mostly to ensure that the answer stays usefull even if the linked page goes down and/or changes. There is a balance to be struck between copying the page wholesale and simply linking to it, but as long a the link dying doesn't make your answer _completely useless_, it should be all good.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, download [Steam Cloud File Manager Lite](https://github.com/GMMan/SteamCloudFileManagerLite) (you can find binaries on the releases part of the repository) and extract it somewhere.

After you extract it, make sure steam client is open. After that, open the program and write "440" (or id of the game you want to wipe) in the box in the top.

[image: Application]

Once you do that, it'll list all the files in the Steam Cloud of that game. Just click on the files and press delete.

Comment: Sorry for no pictures of the list, but I had nothing in my TF2 directory.

Comment: I'm on a Mac, but if there is in fact an API exposed for this I might be able to make the calls myself.  Thanks.